# How to write "Intercepting Filter Pattern" like Java's servlet filter in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, design-patterns, filter

I want to know how to write "Intercepting Filter Pattern" like Java's servlet filter in Flex.

And I want to insert it into the classes which have a role of server communicating.

Please show me any sample codes if any...

Comment: don't forget to accept answers to your questions. choose the best answer and click on "check symbol" under the answer rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class which will play a role of connector between your program and server. Put there event listener for server events. Create a constant types for different types of events that server could send to your program. Put a  switch into event listener that receive these events, and re dispatch them to the specific places,  depending on which type of the event it was.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, milla. But I can't imagine your image concretely. Please show me sample codes if possible.